# vim: "extend" window into next window

Tags: vim, window

Let's say I have this layout in vim:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
|  a  |     |     |
|     |     |     |
+-----+  c  |  d  |
|     |     |     |
|  b  |     |     |
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

is it possible to end up with this layout:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
|  a  |  c  |     |
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+  d  |
|           |     |
|     b     |     |
|           |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

like an "extend right" command ?

PS. Don't tell me to use `ctrl-w J` on *b* then `ctrl-w L` on *d*, my layout is actually more complex then this. I'm really looking for an "extend right" command if it exists.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think a built-in command for this exists. You'd have to cobble it together with `<c-w> J` and `<c-w L` like you say, and for more complex layouts that could get darn tricky.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to implement as a feature since there can be a lot of edge case scenarios to consider, also why vim doesn't do this natively.

If you don't like the option of using `ctrl-w J` on *b* then `ctrl-w L` on *d* then the simplest approach would be to close the *c* split and then open a new vertical split on *a* and open the buffer / file within it that you desired.

Answer (score 0):

This is brittle, but probably better than nothing!

```
function! ExtendRight()
    let l:start=winnr()
    exe "normal \<c-w>l"
    let l:shrink=bufnr('%')
    close
    exe "normal " . l:start . "\<c-w>w"
    exe "normal \<c-w>k"
    vsplit
    exe "b " . l:shrink
endfunction
```

You can map it with `nnoremap <c-w>e :call ExtendRight()<CR>`.